# Media player (Windows or Linux) that's easy to control with a gamepad?

Tags: linux, windows, media-player, logitech-gamepad

I have a Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710 that I'd like to be able to use as a remote control for a media player on my PC. I currently map the gamepad to certain hot-keys for use with VLC, but I can't say it's ideal.

Is there a media player out there that's easy to control with a gamepad *and* supports a wide range of file types?

Bonus points if it has an internal video library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) appears to have all the functionality I need.

- Works on Windows **and** Linux (among others)
- Gamepad support built in
- Video and music library
- Reads media directly from my Windows Shares

The only thing I needed to do to make this specific gamepad work with it on Windows, was:

1. Copy `%ProgramFiles%\XBMC\system\keymaps\joystick.Logitech.RumblePad.2.xml` to
   `%AppData%\XBMC\userdata\keymaps\Wireless Gamepad F710.xml`.
2. Change all occurrences of `Logitech Logitech Cordless RumblePad 2` to
   `Logitech Cordless RumblePad 2 USB`.
3. Make sure the gamepad is set to DirectInput mode when XBMC is launched.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. If you don't, the gamepad will get detected as `Wireless Gamepad F710 (Controller)` and will not work with the RumblePad 2 profile.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use [XPadder](http://www.xpadder.com/) & here's a [tutorial](http://www.beingmanan.com/wp/2009/08/use-the-xbox-360-controller-to-control-your-pc/) to use it to control your desktop.